# excel checking if user input is within the range

Tags: excel, vba

I just started learning about excel macro and I want to create a spread sheet which will error check for upper and lower limit.
first setting the limits (user can choose those on one case)
and then prompting for three inputs for capacitance, I want to check if those values are within the specified range
can someone please point me in the right direction
thank you

Comment: If you google "Userfoms VBA" you will find some useful tutorials that will get you started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question, I don't know if you're asking for a range of cells or a range of values, so:

**Alternative 1:**

This code would check if cells are within range "A1:B3".

you should put it behind the worksheet's code

[image: Where to put it]

Adjust it to fit your needs

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim evalRange As Range

    Set evalRange = Me.Range("A1:B3")

    If Not Intersect(Target, evalRange) Is Nothing Then

        MsgBox "User changed something within evaluated range"

    End If

End Sub
```

**Alternative 2**

Put this code in a standard vba module, run it with F8 or F5 and adjust it to fit your needs:

```
Public Sub AskForValues()

    Dim inputValue As Variant
    Dim lowerLimit As Long
    Dim upperLimit As Long

    lowerLimit = 1
    upperLimit = 10

    inputValue = InputBox("Please enter a value")


    If Not IsNumeric(inputValue) Then
        MsgBox "The value you entered is not a number"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If inputValue < lowerLimit Or inputValue > upperLimit Then
        MsgBox "The value you entered is not within range"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox "you entered..." & inputValue

End Sub
```

Remember to mark the answer if it helps.